# E11000 duplicate key error when inserting array with existing first element in a Unique Compound Index

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have a collection: `test` and i have a Unique Compound Index created with this:
`db.collection('test').createIndex({ path: 1, price: 1, type: 1 }, { unique: true });`

path is an array, price and type are strings

and i'm trying to insert documents:

```
db.test.insertOne({ path: [ 'Some', 'Thing' ], price: '1.00', type: '' })
```

This works, and i can see the document in my collection but when i try to insert another document:

```
db.test.insertOne({ path: [ 'Some', 'Thing', 'Else' ], price: '1.00', type: '' })
```

i get this error:

```
2019-08-20T11:04:10.560+0300 E QUERY    [js] WriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: api.test index: path_1_price_1_type_1 dup key: { : "Some", : "1.00", : "" } :
WriteError({
        "index" : 0,
        "code" : 11000,
        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: api.test index: path_1_price_1_type_1 dup key: { : \"Some\", : \"1.00\", : \"\" }",
        "op" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d5ba97a19d534f6cc2fc050"),
                "path" : [
                        "Some",
                        "Thing"
                ],
                "price" : "1.00",
                "type" : ""
        }
})
WriteError@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:461:48
Bulk/mergeBatchResults@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:841:49
Bulk/executeBatch@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:906:13
Bulk/this.execute@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:1150:21
DBCollection.prototype.insertOne@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:252:9
@(shell):1:1
```

I've tried to use updateOne with upsert:true but i'm getting the same error
And even if the first field value is a array it seems to red only the first element when trying to insert and giving me the `dup key: { : "Some", : "1.00", : "" }` when in fact i'm trying to insert an array...

here is the full code i run inside my console:

```
db.collection('test').createIndex({ path: 1, price: 1, type: 1 }, { unique: true });
db.test.insertOne({ path: [ 'Some', 'Thing' ], price: '1.00', type: '' })
db.test.insertOne({ path: [ 'Some', 'Thing', 'Else' ], price: '1.00', type: '' })
```

The path can be different, so if i try to insert this:

```
db.test.insertOne({ path: [ 'Some', 'Thing' ], price: '1.00', type: '' })
db.test.insertOne({ path: [ 'Bla', 'Bla' ], price: '1.00', type: '' })
```

it works

But if one of the array elements exists:

```
db.test.insertOne({ path: [ 'Bla', 'Thing' ], price: '1.00', type: '' })
```

I get that error

Can anyone help me fix this problem? I need the path, price and type to be unique, but I just need the path to be unique as an array not unique as in any element of the array

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB, indexing arrays is called a Multikey index. In this case, MongoDB indexes each value of the array separately. That's why you get your duplicate key.

A work around would be to "hide" your array in a sub document to prevent the actual indexing of the array.

For example:

```
{
  "path": {
     "sub_doc" : [ "Bla", "Things" ]
  }
}
```

Be careful that in this case the elements of the array are not indexed anymore. Meaning you won't be able to request directly on `"Bla"` or `"Things"` through the index. Only the full object `sub_doc`.

Comment: So to ensure the Unique Compound Index I can use ```db.test.createIndex({ path.sub_doc: 1, price: 1, type: 1 }, { unique: true });```?

Comment: No no, if you do that you'll get exactly in the same issue.
You have to do `db.test.createIndex({ path: 1, price: 1, type: 1 }, { unique: true });`.
In this case MongoDB will index `path` as a whole and not look at the sub-array.